# In C++, must operator[] () be a member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++, must `operator []()` always be a member function? If yes, why?

I read "An operator must be a member function" in book

"The C++ Programming Language Special Edition" page 287.

Comment: Yes, because it is supposed to access the private members of the class.

Comment: You shoudl read this other post from Stack Overflow, it is very interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719

Comment: it shouldn't be. saying that it has to access private members is pure speculation...

Comment: @Morwenn It can order pizza, too.

Comment: @jrok Talking about pizza and private members at once is kind of awkward.

Comment: @Morwenn, yes the `[]` is overloading to access private members of the class, but why can't it be a friend function? A friend function can also access private variables and some operators are overloaded using friend functions.

Comment: @SimonZ If I had to hazard a guess I would say that it is because the standard would then have to introduce the new exception of "function that can only be in-class or friend" and that it had no obvious advantage over just restricting it to in-class everywhere consistently. It's an old design decision though, I don't know whether the rationale is still somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the C++ draft:

> 13.5.5 Subscripting [over.sub]
>
> operator[] shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter. It implements the subscripting syntax
>
> > postfix-expression [ expression ]
>
> Thus, a subscripting expression x[y] is interpreted as x.operator for a class object x of type T if T::operator exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3.3).

---

<strike>I can't find it explicit in the spec, but I'm assuming the reason is because it's expected to return an lvalue.</strike>

Scratch that: it didn't make sense. It returns an lvalue of the subscripted type not the object type.