# Operatrator [] as non-static function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Code:

```
SchedulingItem operator[](Schedule obj,int el){
    return obj.OfVector().at(el);
}
```

Error:

```
academia::SchedulingItem academia::operator[](academia::Schedule, int)' must be a nonstatic member function
     SchedulingItem operator[](Schedule obj,int el)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: operator [] must be a member function that takes one parameter,

Comment: Some dupe. Not even about the same freakin' operator. Plus the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210718/in-c-must-operator-be-a-member-function

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that, just as the message says, this function must be a non-static member function.

[That's simply a law of C++, for `operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

You've instead made it a non-member, or "free" function.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing about the mistake in this answer.

Comment: Apparently it's rude to expect people to actually read the error message telling them exactly what the problem is and how to fix it

Comment: @M.M: It's a strange world we live in

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` must be a non-static member of your `Schedule` class, eg:

```
class Schedule
{
private:
    std::vector<SchedulingItem> m_vec;
public:
    SchedulingItem& operator[](int el);
};

SchedulingItem& Schedule::operator[](int el)
{
    return m_vec.at(el);
}
```