# Overload operator [] -in not non-static memberfunction

Tags: operator-overloading

```
SchedulingItem operator[](Schedule obj,int el) {
    return obj.OfVector().at(el);
}
```

When using this code gets : SchedulingItem operator[](Schedule obj,int el) must be a nonstatic member function
     SchedulingItem operator[](Schedule obj,int el) Where is problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operatrator \[\] as non-static function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010316/operatrator-as-non-static-function)

Comment: Use a language tag next time. And the search function